# object has no attribute get

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working with the tkinter module in python 3.3 I am relatively new to this and am working with entry boxes. for some reason when I run the following code I get an error message saying AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. Could someone explain to me why? I did a similar program with a single entry that workded just fine.

```
from tkinter import *
master =Tk()
class quad(object):
def __init__(self, ae, be, ce):
    self.ae = ae
    self.be = be
    self.ce = ce

def calculate(self):
    a = self.ae.get()
    b = self.be.get()
    c = self.ce.get()
    A = float(a)
    B = float(b)
    C = float(c)
    D = (-B)/(2*A)
    E = ((B**2 -4*A*C)**(.5))/(2*A)
    first = D + E
    second = D - E
    print(first, "\n", second)
Label(master, text='A=').grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(master, text='B=').grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(master, text='C=').grid(row=2, column=0)      
ae = Entry(master).grid(row=0, column=1)
be = Entry(master).grid(row=1, column=1)
ce = Entry(master).grid(row=2, column=1)
model =quad(ae, be, ce)
Button(master, text='submit', width=10, command=model.calculate).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Variations of this question have been asked several times on this site. For example [Python TkInter - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/python-tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a very close look at the error message: what does it say? It is telling you precisely what the problem is. It's even telling you the line number.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Notice where it says `'NoneType'`? That means that some variable is `None` even though you think it is something else. And obviously, `None` doesn't have a method named `get`. So, you have to ask yourself, why it is `None`?

You don't show it in your question, but it's likely that the error is happening on the `ae` variable (and also on the `be` and `ce` variables). So the question is, why are they `None`?

The reason they are `None` is that you are setting them like this:

> ae = Entry(master).grid(row=0, column=1)

In python, when you do `x=a().b()`, x gets the value of `b()`. Thus, you are setting `ae` to the value of the `grid(...)` statement, and the grid statement always returns `None`.

The solution is to separate your widget creation from layout, which is generally a good practice even if you don't need to save references to the GUI widgets:

```
ae = Entry(...)
be = Entry(...)
ce = Entry(...)
...
ae.grid(...)
be.grid(...)
ce.grid(...)
```